# value_type size

Tags: boost, tuples, value-type

is there any ways of retrieving the number of elements in

```
typename X::value_type
```

where X is a vec of tuples?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tuple is a [boost.tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_advanced_interface.html):

```
boost::tuples::length<X::value_type>::value
```

For other tuple types, you'd use something similar, but it depends on the library it's from.

Comment: yes, thanks. I just found it out a minute ago within boost library. The problem is that there isn't much documentation within the code.

Comment: do you know how to set a specific element of a tuple?

Comment: @Banana: `t.get<N>() = new_value`